# Alone MFCC can identify difference between sound?

Tags: noise, sound, mfcc, signal-identification

I am doing a project to identify different drum beats. There are lots of features like MFCC, Chroma Values, Spectral Bandwidth, Spectral Centroid, Zero Crossing Rate, etc. But most of the projects are done by only using MFCC, So can we use only MFCC values to detect the difference between all sound types and noise too.